# How does GSON decide which TypeAdapter it uses during deserialization?

Tags: java, json, google-app-engine, rest, gson

I have the problem, that App Engine returns Long/long values as "String". Here is part of the returned JSON file:

```
  "stringObject" : "This is a string.",
  "integerPrimitive" : -3,
  "intergerObject" : 3333,
  "longPrimitive" : "1234567890123456789",
  "longObject" : "1234567890123456789",
```

and the server side datatypes that produced it:

```
private String stringObject = "This is a string.";
private int integerPrimitive = -3;
private Integer intergerObject = 3333;
private long longPrimitive = 1234567890123456789L;
private Long longObject = 1234567890123456789L;
```

I have written a TypeAdapter to treat Long, but it seems that during deserialization GSON does not look at the target variable, but at the JSON itself. In other words: It still seems to invoke the String TypeAdapter for Long/long, at least breakpoints in my TypeAdapter are never reached (which could also be an artifact of reflection, though). Is this possible or is there another problem with my TypeAdapter? How does GSON determine which adapter it calls.

```
public class LongTypeAdapter extends TypeAdapter<Long> {

    // Long/long is converted to String by AppEngine 0L -> "0"

    @Override public void write(JsonWriter writer, Long value) throws IOException {
        if (value == null) {
            writer.nullValue();
            return;
        }
        String text = "\"" + String.valueOf(value) + "\"";
        writer.value(text);
    }

    @Override public Long read(JsonReader reader) throws IOException {
        if (reader.peek() == JsonToken.NULL) {
            reader.nextNull();
            return null;
        }
        String text = reader.nextString();
        text = text.replaceAll("\"", "");
        Long value = Long.parseLong(text);
        return value;
    }

}
```

I debugged into GSON and my adapter is properly registered, so I would most probably exclude a registration issue here.

---

This is how the adapter is registered:

```
public class Backend {

    // Singleton
    private static volatile BackendInterface service = null;
    private Backend() {} // exists only to defeat instantiation

    public static BackendInterface api() {
        if (service == null) { // lazy initialization

            final Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
                    .registerTypeAdapter(Long.class, new LongTypeAdapter())
                    .create();

            RestAdapter restAdapter = new RestAdapter.Builder()
                    .setEndpoint(Constants.BACKEND_API_ENDPOINT)
                    .setClient(new OkClient())
                    .setLogLevel(RestAdapter.LogLevel.FULL) // TODO remove full logging for production
                    .setConverter(new GsonConverter(gson))
                    .build();

            service = restAdapter.create(BackendInterface.class);

        }
        return service;
    }

}
```

And here is how I use it:

```
Test test = Backend.api().getTest(2L);
```

Comment: You should test with less moving parts. Does it work when you directly call `gson.getJson(myObject)` ? How about when you call `gson.getJson(myObject)` outside of App Engine, like in a `public static void main()`method ? I am unable to reproduce your issue with Gson 2.2.4.

Comment: I am on the client side, not on App Engine. I have not modified serialization on App Engine, and I don't want to do that. My problem is that when I receive an HTML body from the API after a request, that body is parsed by GSON. And here GSON seems to use the String adapter for Long/long instead of the TypeAdapter which I have supplied. Is there any way to test this detached?

Comment: My bad. You might want to remove the google-app-engine tag as it is not related to app engine at all. My app engine apps do not exhibit this behavior at all.

Comment: I probably hadn't specified this clear enough, sorry. I leave the app-engine tag in, though, as this is the backend. Most probably your app engine apps do not exhibit this behavior because you are using the Google generated endpoint client. This works well for me too, but that client does not implement caching and multithreading, so it is awfully slow: http://instructure.github.io/blog/2013/12/09/volley-vs-retrofit/ [Async task in the comparison means google-http-client libraries].

Comment: Same thing, you need to remove the moving parts such as your rest client. Create a String containing your test json data (the one at the top of your question) and then call `gson.fromJson()` on it. Does it return the correct results ?

Can you also explain exactly what you're getting that is not satisfying ? On the tests I've performed, gson deserializes correctly even if the long attributes are quoted.

Answer (score 0):

Well you have to register the new type adapter:

```
final Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().registerTypeAdapter(Long.class,
                    new LongTypeAdapter()).create();
```

I hope that helps

Comment: Yes, I did that. I am using Retrofit and I have added the code above. The TypeAdapter also appears in the factories collection in GSON, so it is apparently correctly registered.

Comment: And when putting a breakpoint on .registerTypeAdapter line you see it getting there? I tried this with main() and it worked for me.

Comment: Yes, the TypeAdapter is registered. It comes across the breakpoint where it's registered, but it never reaches a breakpoint in my TypeAdapter. (It also doesn't reach breakpoints in built-in TypeAdapters, but that's probably because the code is reflected.) Registration is not the problem. I suspect GSON tries to detect the datatype from the HTML body instead of the class. As it finds String there, it doesn't care about my TypeAdapter. Could also be an implementation glitch, but to me it looks like that. Can anybody confirm how GSON decides during deserialization.